# Background Image not Loading in Safari

Tags: css, safari

Very weird issue. The nav-bar background image is loading fine in all browsers except for Safari.

http://lapalomafunrun.com/

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#navbar {
width: 100%;
height: 53px;
margin-top: -10px;
position:relative;
z-index:1;
background: url("http://lapalomafunrun.com/wp-content/themes/funrun/images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll center top / 100% 63px transparent !important;
background: url("http://lapalomafunrun.com/wp-content/themes/funrun/images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent\9 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS 3 background shorthand [isn't supported](http://benfrain.com/css3-background-shorthand-still-not-working-cross-browser/) in Safari 6.02 (which I'll assume you're using since it isn't working). You can use the CSS 2.1 `background` shorthand syntax but will need to remove the `background-size` property to its own declaration:

```
#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 53px;
    margin-top: -10px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    background: url("http://lapalomafunrun.com/wp-content/themes/funrun/images/navbar.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent !important;
    background-size: 100% 63px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just having the issue where I couldn't apply a background-image property to the `<main>` element in Safari.  Come to find that Safari (currently) doesn't recognize `<main>` as a block element, as can happen with many of the implementations of HTML5, so setting `<main>` to `display:block` did the trick for me.  Hopefully that helps.